# SQL expression to select specific month across years

Tags: sql, arcgis-pro

What is the ArcGIS SQL expression to select all rows containing the month of May across several years?

Desired records highlighted in Excel:
[image: 4 of 10 rows meet criteria]

The source table is in a file geodatabase and I'm using ArcGIS Pro v2.2.4.

#### Attempts so far

I tried using the wildcard characters for strings listed in the [Pro SQL reference](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm) but they (unsurprisingly) yield "invalid syntax" error:

```
SAMPLE_DATE = date '%-05-%'
SAMPLE_DATE = date '__-02-__'
```

KB article [How To: Search for specific parts of a date stored in a Date-Time field](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011531) offers `EXTRACT(MONTH ...) = nn` but that returns zero records.

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SAMPLE_DATE) = 05
```

[image: SQL valid but zero records]

Answer (score 1):

The KB article *is* correct, and so is the warning message after a fashion: **In the Definition Query box the expression is run against the results of the *preceding* expression** in effect when the tool was opened or last verified.

I had been entering a series of expressions one after the other narrowing in on the right solution. After clearing the expression, closing the dialog and then re-opening Definition Query I get the expected results. (Note: there is a 1 to 3 second pause after closing the dialog to when the table view is updated.)

[image: Fresh def-query session]
[image: results showing only May across many years]